# Meteor Single Signon oAuth Popup is Blank! (cross-origin frame error)

Tags: javascript, meteor, cross-domain

I have no idea why this is happening.  We finally launched our app, everything works on the staging server, and then I deploy to an identical setup - and now this is happening - and I can't figure out why.

You can see it happening for yourself: go to http://www.crunchyserial.com/
[image]

Here is the error in the console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.crunchyserial.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at http://www.crunchyserial.com/packages/oauth/end_of_popup_response.js:18:39
    at http://www.crunchyserial.com/packages/oauth/end_of_popup_response.js:37:3
```

If you refresh the blank oauth window, it closes and then you get this error:[image]

and on the server log you get this:

```
[00.00.00.00]{"line":"431","file":"oauth.js","message":"Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. failed [400] {   \"error\" : \"invalid_grant\",   \"error_description\" : \"Code was already redeemed.\" }","time":{"$date":1497382695634},"level":"warn"}
[00.00.00.00]Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. failed [400] {   "error" : "invalid_grant",   "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed." }
[00.00.00.00]    at getTokens (packages/google-oauth/google_server.js:107:7)
    at Object.getServiceData [as handleOauthRequest] (packages/google-oauth/google_server.js:81:35)
    at OAuth._requestHandlers.(anonymous function) (packages/oauth2.js:27:31)
    at middleware (packages/oauth.js:203:5)
    at packages/oauth.js:176:5
{"line":"431","file":"oauth.js","message":"Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. failed [400] {   \"error\" : \"invalid_grant\",   \"error_description\" : \"Code was already redeemed.\" }","time":{"$date":1497382701056},"level":"warn"}
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. failed [400] {   "error" : "invalid_grant",   "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed." }
    at getTokens (packages/google-oauth/google_server.js:107:7)
    at Object.getServiceData [as handleOauthRequest] (packages/google-oauth/google_server.js:81:35)
    at OAuth._requestHandlers.(anonymous function) (packages/oauth2.js:27:31)
    at middleware (packages/oauth.js:203:5)
[00.00.00.00]    at packages/oauth.js:176:5
```

Here is the `settings.json` I use in my `./deploy` directory for the production server:

```
{
  "public": {
    "analyticsSettings": {
      "Google Analytics" : {"trackingId": "//redacted//"}
    }
  },
  "private": {
    "oAuth": {
      "google": {
        "clientId": "//redacted//",
        "secret": "//redacted//",
        "loginStyle": "popup"
      },
      "facebook": {
        "appId": "//redacted//",
        "secret": "//redacted//",
        "loginStyle": "popup"
      },
      "twitter": {
        "consumerKey": "//redacted//",
        "secret": "//redacted//"
        "loginStyle": "popup"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Oddly enough, there is no difference between "redirect" and "popup" loginStyles... I don't notice ANY behavior difference in the app.

This is my `mup.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '//redacted//',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: "//redacted//"
      // password:
      // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'CrunchySerial',
    path: '../../CrunchySerial',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://www.crunchyserial.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },

    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    deployCheckWaitTime: 400
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: //redacted//,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

I've tried the ROOT_URL with and without a `/` I've updated to all the latest versions...  And I still have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Either you fixed it, or you need to clear your cache and try again. There might be a cookie with some staging server data in it that's goofing you up.

Comment: Strange... I tried clearing my cache and it's still not working.  I wonder if I regenerate the keys if that has anything to do with it.  I'll try that.  What browser did you use @Will?

Comment: Thanks @Will it was your comment that helped me understand that since it's working for you and not for me - there has to be a difference... And THERE WAS...  www.crunchyserial.com and crunchyserial.com are two different domains.  And because the oauth uri is based on the ROOT_URL you can really only have *one* or *the other* but not **both**.  I'm replying with an answer right now.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I didn't see your question until just now.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution: oauth, ROOT_URL, redirect_uri and www.domain.com vs domain.com

Your oauth script will only work from one domain - and when you have a ROOT_URL, it uses this in the uri that your oauth sends in it's request.  Also, you have to register which redirect_uri(s) are valid with some services (like google).  So oauth will only work from ONE subdomain/domain.  You have to pick *www* or *no-www* - **not both**.  I chose to keep www and setup both a DNS redirect, and a programmatic redirect (just to be sure).

### DNS Redirect from @ to www.[your-domain].com:

We're using NameCheap, so the `URL Redirect Record` was easy to setup.  Here is [NameCheap's documentation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-do-i-set-up-a-url-redirect-for-a-domain).

### Programmatic redirect in Meteor:

This is how I force a redirect in Meteor check for www and enforce it if it's not there.

`File Location: [project]/imports/startup/client/force_www_redirect.js`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'

Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (location.host.indexOf('www.crunchyserial.com') !== 0) {
        location = 'http://www.crunchyserial.com'
    }
})
```

and I just make sure this is the first code my client startup sees by importing it first.

`File Location: [project]/imports/startup/client/index.js`

```
// force www.crunchyserial.com
import './force_www_redirect'

// Configure Login Buttons UI
import './login_button_configuration'

// Configure atForm
import './useraccounts_configuration'

// Run the Routes
import './routes'
```

which is called from `[project]/client/main.js`:

```
import '../imports/startup/client'
```